# Issue displaying the summary view of a custom content part in Orchard CMS using Placement.info

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I created a custom part called PresentationPart and its placed.

In the placement.info I have

```
<Match ContentType="Presentation">
    <Match DisplayType="Summary">
        <Place Parts_PresentationPart_Summary="Content:after"/>
    </Match>
    <Match DisplayType="Detail">
        <Place Parts_PresentationPart="Content:after"/>
    </Match>
</Match>
```

The folder layout is

```
Views ->
    EditorTemplates ->
        Parts ->
            Parts_PresentationPart.cshtml   
    Parts ->
         Parts_PresentationPart.cshtml
         Parts_PresentationPart.Summary.cshtml
```

The view Parts_PresentationPart_Summary is never used (attempting to have summary display in list view).

If I modify Placement.info's Presentation Summary match area to be

```
<Match DisplayType="Summary">
    <Place Parts_PresentationPart="Content:before"/>
    <Place Parts_PresentationPart_Summary="Content:after"/>
</Match>
```

The normal view will display.

What is required to get the summary view to display?  Or is there something I am completely skipping?

edit:  I'd skipped the CombinedResult in the display driver.

Original:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(PresentationPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    return ContentShape("Parts_PresentationPart",() => shapeHelper.Parts_PresentationPart(ContentItem: part.ContentItem, Name: part.Name)));
}
```

So what I'll need is something like this?

```
var driverResults = new List<DriverResult>();
driverResults.Add(ContentShape("Parts_PresentationPart", () => shapeHelper.Parts_PresentationPart(ContentItem: part.ContentItem, Name: part.Name)));
driverResults.Add(ContentShape("Parts_PresentationPart_Summary",() => shapeHelper.Parts_PresentationPart(ContentItem: part.ContentItem, Name: part.Name)));
return new CombinedResult(driverResults);
```

Comment: The code you posted with CombinedResult is exactly what should be done to make everything work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the "normal" and "summary" shapes as totally separate ones. 
That being said you should simply not show the "normal" one when displaying the Summary (and vice versa):

```
<Match DisplayType="Summary">
    <Place Parts_PresentationPart="-"/>
    <Place Parts_PresentationPart_Summary="Content:after"/>
</Match>
```

*You haven't posted the **driver Display method**, so I'm not sure what you are returning from it...*

*For this scenario to work you should return the **CombinedResult with both the normal and "summary" shapes inside**. The display manager could then decide which one to display based on the data stored in Placement.info*.

Comment: Updated question with information, I wasn't familiar with CombinedResult but that seems really obvious when actually thinking about whats occurring.